# How to backup a flume master node config?

Tags: flume

I am using flume on a project and am looking for a way to backup the config for the master node. How would I go about doing this? I can't seem to find any info regarding backups on the user guide.

Also, I am looking to have multiple copies of the master node running so that if one fails a copy can take over. I am unaware of how to do this either - does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Solved - The ZooKeeper configuration automatically backs up the master node, as well as enables distributed master systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the zookeeper log dir in flume-conf.xml , the default is tmp dir which doesn't save the configuration between restarts.

see this thread
http://www.mail-archive.com/flume-user@incubator.apache.org/msg00173.html